# zip() and zip(*) seem to give similar results

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the difference between `zip()` and `zip(*)`.

From what I understand, `zip()` can be used to combine two lists, such that elements with a shared index are together. Such as in these examples:

```
dict_list = {'First Name': ['Tom', 'Ann', 'Ben'],
             'Last Name': ['Haverford', 'Perkins', 'Wyatt'],
             'Age': [33, 42, 44],
             'Occupation': ['Administrator', 'Nurse', 'Auditor']}

for first_name, last_name, age, occupation in zip(dict_list['First Name'], dict_list['Last Name'], dict_list['Age'], dict_list['Occupation']):
             print(first_name, last_name, age, occupation)

#result    

Tom Haverford 33 Administrator
Ann Perkins 42 Nurse
Ben Wyatt 44 Auditor
```

So why does it seem to me that sometimes, zip(*) behaves this way? For example:

```
for t in (zip(*dict_list.values())):
    print(t)
#result    

('Tom', 'Haverford', 33, 'Administrator')
('Ann', 'Perkins', 42, 'Nurse')
('Ben', 'Wyatt', 44, 'Auditor')
```

Since my `dict_list.values()` are lists, it seems like `zip(*)` placed all elements with shared indexes in the same tuple. Which is not that much different from the first code, in which I used `zip()` in a `for` loop with dict keys passed into it and with corresponding looping variables

How are `zip()` and `zip(*)` behaving in this case?

Comment: `func(*lst)` is the same as `func(lst[0], lst[1] ... , lst[-1])`

Comment: You just wrote two different ways to do the same thing.  Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: `zip(*)` does unpacking before the real zip operation, whereas `zip()` is directly zip.

Comment: @wim Somehow I came across the same results when using `zip()` and `zip(*)` when I'm expecting them to behave differently. And I'm wondering what the mechanisms are that that led to the same result, when they're supposed to be opposites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> dict_list.values()
[['Tom', 'Ann', 'Ben'], ['Haverford', 'Perkins', 'Wyatt'], [33, 42, 44], ['Administrator', 'Nurse', 'Auditor']]
```

This returns a list containing the four sub-lists.

```
zip(*dict_list.values())
```

And this unpacks that list and passes each of the elements as separate arguments to `zip()`. That's what the `*` unpacking operator does: if you call `zip(*l)` with a list `l` that contains four elements, it calls `zip()` with those four arguments.

Compare it to the first snippet you wrote, which passes the four lists inside `dict_list` as separate arguments to `zip`.

```
zip(dict_list['First Name'], dict_list['Last Name'], dict_list['Age'], dict_list['Occupation'])
```

Both of them end up passing the exact same thing to `zip()`. Naturally, the result is the same.

---

If you want to compare it to a version without the `*`, try:

```
zip(dict_list.values())
```

Now there's a difference:

```
>>> zip(*dict_list.values())
[('Haverford', 'Tom', 33, 'Administrator'), ('Perkins', 'Ann', 42, 'Nurse'), ('Wyatt', 'Ben', 44, 'Auditor')]
>>> zip(dict_list.values())
[(['Haverford', 'Perkins', 'Wyatt'],), (['Tom', 'Ann', 'Ben'],), ([33, 42, 44],), (['Administrator', 'Nurse', 'Auditor'],)]
```

Comment: what value does `t` take then at every loop in the `for` loop with `zip(*)`? I'm still confused about that part.